# Silverlight: a good client-local DB free

Tags: .net, database, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, local-storage

I need to use a client-local-db in Silverlight that can store a maximum of 50000 records in a maximum of 20 tables. Are there any free solutions? I have found something in the web but nothing that works.

Comment: by local do you mean client local or server local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sterling OODB on Codeplex](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) should be able to handle this. The reference application outlined [here](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/07/introducing-sterling-object-oriented.html) has over 500,000 entries in the database so it looks like it should be able to handle your load.

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable that the silverlight app can run outside of the browser with elevated trust you could look at using SQL compact edition (http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/access-local-sql-compact-database-from.html). Otherwise you might consider looking at an object database like db40 (http://www.db4o.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[TurboDB](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html) is an embedded database engine that can handle that amount of data easily also on Silverlight in isolated storage. It can run on medium trust but it is not free.